# __file__ and __line__macro for pl sql scripts

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I have a huge packages in PL/SQL which executed a delete command on a table A.
I want to determine the procedure responsible for this operation.
My idea is to create a trigger on this table to track the "file" and "line" of the deletion.

Is that possible in PL/SQL like in C++ or PHP through **file** and **line** macros.
Otherwise, Is it possible for a trigger to find the name of the stored procedure that deleted data?

Thanks.

Comment: Are there multiple procedures which delete this table and you want to audit which one executes any given deletion? Or is this  a documentation bug and you literally don't know which procedure is responsible?

Comment: Yes, I want to use that for investigation purpose (product issue).

Comment: `dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace()`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if I put this line in the trigger body, Will I get the line performing the deletion?

Comment: No, it's not what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Is this ongoing tracking of rows deleted, or just the occasional check of "Hmmm....a SQL deleted some rows, I wonder where it came from?". If it is the latter, you can get that from V$SQL which tracks the originating PLSQL module that issued the SQL. The columns are PROGRAM_ID and PROGRAM_LINE#.

If you need a full example, I've got one on my site

https://connor-mcdonald.com/2016/01/20/problematic-sql-plsql-is-your-friend/